# Is Dhcp option 53 mandatory in Dhcp offer?

Tags: networking, dhcp, raw-ethernet

I'm trying to find out whether option 53 in DHCP offer is mandatory or not.
I've found this short snippet:
[image]

in [book](https://books.google.fi/books?id=-wevDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=does%20dhcp%20offer%20needs%20to%20have%20option%2053&source=bl&ots=rIRrzNP9xU&sig=ACfU3U3NLVdMwp2PrQHPTShpJ_dyVcADbw&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP7-i4n8D0AhXG66QKHRT6BsYQ6AF6BAgeEAM#v=onepage&q=does%20dhcp%20offer%20needs%20to%20have%20option%2053&f=false) but I'm looking for any confirmation in rfc. I've checked [this one](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2132) but in section about option 53 there is no word of whether it is mandatory.

Do you have any suggestions about where I can find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer in: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131#section-3

> Several options have been defined so far.  One particular option -
> the "DHCP message type" option - **must be included in every DHCP
> message**.  This option defines the "type" of the DHCP message.
> Additional options may be allowed, required, or not allowed,
> depending on the DHCP message type.